# The unicode characters in SMP were encoded by UTF-16 in a UTF-8 encoding html page?

Tags: javascript, html, unicode, encoding, utf-8

Some Unicode characters are in a supplementary multilingual plane, like `'\u{1d4d9}'` ().

Its UTF-8 encoding should be `0xf09d9399` in Python 3:

```py
"\U0001d4d9".encode('utf-8')  # b'\xf0\x9d\x93\x99'
```

But, in a UTF-8 encoded web page, this character is encoded in UTF-16. In Chrome console on `"about:blank"`:

```js
document.write('\u{1d4d9}')
//undefined
s = document.body.innerText
//""
[s.charCodeAt(0).toString(16), s.charCodeAt(1).toString(16)].join(',')
//"d835,dcd9"
```

It's the UTF-16 encoding of that character, not the UTF-8.

BTW, I'm in Chrome 83.0 on Windows 7.

Is this a feature of UTF-8, or Javascript, or HTML5, or HTTP, or Chrome, or Windows 7, or something else?

Comment: JavaScript strings are UTF-16.

Comment: Or better UCS-2

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi although UCS-2 is allowed by the Javascript spec, it is very rare in practice.  Most implementations use UTF-16 instead.